# Pythagorean triple

Tags: c, algorithm

I try to solve [this problem](http://projecteuler.net/problem=9)

> There exists exactly one Pythagorean triplet for which a + b + c = 1000.

I use the Euclid's formula:

[image: Euclid's formula]

My solution is:

```
int a = 0, b = 0, c = 0, m = 0, n = 0;
int abort = 0;

 while(abort == 0)
 {
      m++;
      while(abort == 0 && n < 10000)
      {
          n++;
          if(m > n)
          {
              a = (m*m) - (n*n);
              b = 2*m*n;
              c = (m*m) + (n*n);

              if(a+b+c == 1000 && a > 0 && b > 0 && c > 0 /*&& a < b && b < c*/)
              {
                   exit = 1;
              }
          }
      }
      n = 0;
 }
```

If I run this I got a = 375 b = 200 and c = 425. Which is wrong cause it should be `a < b < c` but if I use the check you see in my code (the part which is commented out) my code runs forever.

So what is my mistake?

Comment: Naming a variable `exit` is a bad idea, as it shadows the standard `exit` function.

Comment: you never set "abbruch" to exit the outer while

Comment: @JoachimPileborg sorry this are just copy paste fails I change that

Comment: `abort` is also a standard function :-)

Comment: haha and I fail again, but well I use in my code a german word there and I just change it here for understanding

Comment: Be careful with the formula! Not all the triplets can be described by it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`a` and `b` are totally equivalent in the formula `a^2 + b^2 = c^2` (unlike `c`, which plays a distinct role). Leave your algorithm as it is, and swap `a` and `b` in your result after you get it, if they happen to be in the "wrong" order.

Formally speaking, given any `a`, `b` and `c` which are a Pythagorean triplet *except* for the fact that `a < b` is not true, and instead `b < a` is, then `b`, `a` and `c` are a Pythagorean triplet.

Answer (score 4):

There's a *typical error* with the formulae set you're using: *not all* the Pythagorean triplets can be described by it (but all *elementary* ones); the *right* set of formulae is

```
  a = k * (m * m - n * n)
  b = k * (2 * m * n)
  c = k * (m * m  + n * n)
```

for instance, a **tiplet (9 12 15)** requires **k = 3**; the set provided is, however, *excessive*: some triples are appeared *twice or more times*, so you'll have to use HashMap or something. In your exact problem for the required triplet (375 200 425) is generated by (m = 20, n = 5, k = 1) so in *this* Project Euler promblem is OK to use shortened formula, but in others you'll have to do with right one.

Answer (score 0):

> Which is wrong cause it should be a < b < c

I assume you're saying it "should be" because you think (m²-n²) < 2mn < (m²+n²).

It is true that m²+n² ≥ 2nm and it is true that m²+n² ≥ m²-n² but it is not true that 2mn ≥ m²-n² (explanation of both below if needed). For example take m = 4 and n = 1. Then `2mn` = 8 which is less than `m²-n²` = 15.

So you shouldn't have `a < b` as a termination condition, it's not what you want.

Basically you have the correct algorithm for finding the answers, but sometimes `a` will be the shortest side and sometimes `b` will. This makes sense, because it's only `c` (the hypoteneuse) that's special in the formula. So instead run the algorithm as you were doing - which will find you the triple - then if you want to return an answer set where `a < b < c` just swap `a` and `b` over before returning.

Finally, as another answerer pointed out, this may not find you the Pythagorean triple you're looking for. For any a²+b²=c², ka²+kb²=kc² will also be true and it may turn out that pa+pb+pc = 1000 (where p²=k)...

---

Explaining the maths:

For real m, n.

`(m-n)² ≥ 0` so `m²-2mn-n² ≥ 0` and `m²-n² ≥ 2mn`.

(first result)

Then (second result)

```
m²+n² ≥ m²-n²
```

is trivial for real m and n since m²≥0 and n²≥0.